# How can I get the final height of the UICollectionView after loading data?

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UIScrollView and a UICollectionView in it.

I want to know the final height of the UICollectionView after date loading finished so that I can update UIScrollView's height and it can scroll.

How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, why are you using a `UIScrollView`? `UICollectionView` itself has a scroll a view in it.

Comment: I want UICollectionView scrolls inside UIScrollView. And ScrollView will more views in it that should scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use the `UICollectionView`'s `layoutIfNeeded` method to correctly get the content size. This code might work fine:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
CGSize collectionViewSize = self.collectionView.contentSize;
CGFloat heightOfCollectionView = collectionViewSize.height;
CGFloat widthOfCollectionView = collectionViewSize.width;
```

Note: `layoutIfNeeded` synchronously calls to update all the subviews of the `collectionView` and doesn't return until the views are properly layouted.